How to Perform Pagination with Sorting on DynamoDB Using CreatedAt Attribute in Python?
I'm working with AWS DynamoDB using Python, and I have a table defined as follows using AWS SAM:
RecommendedTalesNewTable:
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  Properties:
    TableName: 'RecommendedTalesNew'  # New table name
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: 'Id'
        AttributeType: 'S'
      - AttributeName: 'CreatedAt'
        AttributeType: 'S'
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: 'Id'
        KeyType: 'HASH'
      - AttributeName: 'CreatedAt'
        KeyType: 'RANGE'
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: 'CreatedAtIndex'
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: 'Id'
            KeyType: 'HASH'
          - AttributeName: 'CreatedAt'
            KeyType: 'RANGE'
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: 'ALL'
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5

My goal is to paginate through the items in the RecommendedTalesNew table, sorted by the CreatedAt attribute. To achieve this, I am using the following Python code:
def get_paged_data(paginator_type, query_params, next_token=None):
    dynamodb = client('dynamodb')
    paginator = dynamodb.get_paginator(paginator_type)
    if next_token is not None and next_token!="None":
        query_params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = json.loads(next_token)

page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**query_params)
items = []
for page in page_iterator:
    items.extend(page['Items'])
    next_token = page.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
    if len(items) != 0:
        break
return deseriliaze_dynamodata(items), next_token, next_token==None

def deseriliaze_dynamodata(items):
    return list(map(lambda item : deseriliaze(item), items))
def get_recommended_tales(event, context):
    limit = int(event['queryStringParameters'].get('limit', 10))
    last_evaluated_key = event['queryStringParameters'].get('lastEvaluatedKey', None)

    query_params = {
        'TableName': "RecommendedTalesNew",
        'Limit': limit,
    }
try:
    items, next_token, end_of_data = get_paged_data("query", query_params, last_evaluated_key)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "Tales retrieved successfully",
            "tales": items,
            'LastEvaluatedKey': next_token
        }),
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
except Exception as e:
    return {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "body": json.dumps({"error": str(e)}),
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

However, I'm encountering the following error when I run the get_recommended_tales function:
ClientError('An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.')
I understand that I need to specify a KeyConditionExpression, but since I want to sort by CreatedAt and paginate through the items, I'm not sure how to structure the query_params correctly.
How should I adjust my code to correctly query and paginate through the table based on the CreatedAt attribute, or is there a better approach to achieve this?

You need to use Scan not Query, as you want all items:
items, next_token, end_of_data = get_paged_data("scan", query_params, 

It's important to know that you won't get all items returned in order, but each key will return it's data in order, there will be no order to your keys in the results, but it'll be deterministic.
If you want all items returned in order then this blog post will help you understand what's needed:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/effective-data-sorting-with-amazon-dynamodb/
